# Update Existing Attendees Calendar in outlook Api

Tags: node.js, api, office365, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

**How to update existing attendees calendar event by adding new attendee using Outlook Update API?**

I have created one Recurring event with two attendees (assume A and B).I will update the same event by adding new attendee (C) using Update API.Then successfully updated Organizer calendar but when I check A's and B's attendees calendar there it is not updating ,it is not showing newly added C attendees in A and B's calendar.

Any one have idea about this?

Comment: It appears that updates only send to the newly added or removed attendees. In Outlook/OWA you are usually prompted to send to just the new/removed, or to send to everyone. I'll check with our devs and update this.

Comment: Hello Jason,any update on this?

Comment: I've reported it to the dev team, there's a work item to improve this. I don't have a time frame to share though.

Comment: Is there any option or field to select that updates need to send to everyone?